# classes for the similar entities

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

I'm developing the software which calculates and shows different reports in tables. But structures of tables has not big differences, many columns are the same.  A first I created one class for each report , e.g. :

```
    class Student()
    {
      int Class {get; set;}
      int Name {get; set;}
      int Age {get; set;}
    }

    class Employee()
    {
      int Name {get; set;}
      int Age {get; set;}
      int Salary{get; set;}
    }
... and more similar classes
```

But after creating some classes I realised, that many of them have common properties, and I can create the common class:

```
        class HumanReport()
        {
          int Class {get; set;}//doesn't exist for Employee(null)
          int Name {get; set;}
          int Age {get; set;} 
          int Salary{get; set;}// doesn't exist for Student
        }
```

But in this case many properties will contain NULL. Which way would be more appropriate for the object oriented programming?

Comment: Create abstract Class/ Interface "PersonalDetails" with common properties First Name, Last Name and you can inherit that class in derived classes employee,Student. You can handle NULL using getter/setter

Answer (score 5):

You should create a base class with the common fields and then extend it for the specialised ones

```
class Human
    {
      int Name {get; set;}
      int Age {get; set;} 
    }

class Employee : Human
    {
      int Salary{get; set;}
    }

class Student : Human
    {
      int Class {get; set;}
    }
```

This is called **Inheritance** and is a key feature of OOP.

Here is the MSDN documentation on the concept of Inheritance.

[Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would say create it such that the base class has the members that is all the classes.

Something like

```
class HumanReport
{
    int Name {get; set;}
    int Age {get; set;} 
}
class Student : HumanReport
{
  int Class {get; set;}
}

class Employee : HumanReport
{
  int Salary{get; set;}
}
```

I think you should have a read here

[Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Inheritance, together with encapsulation and polymorphism, is one of
>   the three primary characteristics (or pillars) of object-oriented
>   programming. Inheritance enables you to create new classes that reuse,
>   extend, and modify the behavior that is defined in other classes. The
>   class whose members are inherited is called the base class, and the
>   class that inherits those members is called the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the properties that all (or many) of your reports will have into one class:

```
class Person
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int Age {get; set;}
}
```

And then have special classes that inherit from those:

```
class Student : Person
{
    int Class {get; set;}
}

class Employee : Person
{
    int Salary {get; set;}
}
```

This way you don't repeat yourself. You may want to familiarize yourself with [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is one of the core concepts of Object Oriented Programming.